# Beamer: using \only makes vertical spacing to change

Tags: beamer, only

My presentation slide has 3 "steps", meaning initially there's something written at first, then one more part appears, then one more. I'm using the `\only<>` command for this (I cannot use `itemize \item<>` now).

My problem is at every "step" the spacing between lines reduces by a bit, making an annoying shrinking effect 2 times. When all 3 parts are on the slide everything fits nicely. I tried inserting various `\vspace{-1em}` commands to have a reduced **from the beginning**, but the effect remains.

I made a MWE, my slide has the same structure:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Title}
\only<1->{
\alert{\textbf{Title text:}}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item  List item $(2^n, 3^n, 4^n, \dots)$
  \begin{itemize}
    \item  \lipsum[1][1] $(2^n, 3^n, \dots)$
    \item[] \lipsum[1][2]: $e^n$ 
    \item  \lipsum[1][3] $(2^n, 3^n, \dots)$
    \item[] \lipsum[1][4] $e^n$ 
  \end{itemize} 
  \item  List item $2^{abc} \bigcup 3^\text{def}$
\end{enumerate}
}
\only<2->{
\alert{\textbf{Title text:}}\\
\lipsum[2][1]
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \tau(n) & \leq & 2^n \\ 
          & \leq & n^{O(\log n)}
\end{eqnarray*}
}
\only<3->{
\lipsum[2][2]: $$a(n) = \sum_i b_i$$
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are only adding stuff to your frame and don't replace text, so you can simply use `\visible` instead of `\only`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Title}
\visible<1->{
\alert{\textbf{Title text:}}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item  List item $(2^n, 3^n, 4^n, \dots)$
  \begin{itemize}
    \item  \lipsum[1][1] $(2^n, 3^n, \dots)$
    \item[] \lipsum[1][2]: $e^n$ 
    \item  \lipsum[1][3] $(2^n, 3^n, \dots)$
    \item[] \lipsum[1][4] $e^n$ 
  \end{itemize} 
  \item  List item $2^{abc} \bigcup 3^\text{def}$
\end{enumerate}
}
\visible<2->{
\alert{\textbf{Title text:}}\\
\lipsum[2][1]
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \tau(n) & \leq & 2^n \\ 
          & \leq & n^{O(\log n)}
\end{eqnarray*}
}
\visible<3->{
\lipsum[2][2]: $$a(n) = \sum_i b_i$$
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! Is there an explanation why `\only<>` had this behaviour? Also what is the difference between `only` and `visible`?

Comment: @Rolf The main difference is that `\only` makes the content only appear on the desired slides, it is not there on the other slides .Whereas `\visible` makes it visible, which means that content is still there on the other slides, just not visible and thus reserves the required space etc.